# How can I redirect storage of Multipass VMs?

Tags: multipass

I've just been trying out Multipass and can see great value in using it for training and testing. Unfortunately with the small SSD I use as the root volume in my server it quickly ran out of space.

I can't seem to locate the path where the disks are stored and it doesn't appear to be configurable. Is there a nice way to use a custom path for VM storage and image storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's currently supported through the `MULTIPASS_STORAGE` environment variable. How to set it up for various systems is documented [here](https://multipass.run/docs/configure-multipass-storage).

You will need to start from scratch, or migrate the data on your own. An alternative approach using symbolic links is described [here](https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/566#issuecomment-641581396).

Comment: this feature is very important, millions of people uses small SSDs as primary disk these days